# In boost::python how to wrap an overrideable function which takes a container of pointers to C++ objects and returns a pointer to one of them?

Tags: pointers, wrapper, boost-python

I'm wrapping a C++ framework with boost::python and I need to make a C++ method overrideable in python. This is a hook method, which is needed by the framework and has a default implementation in C++, which iterates through a list (passed as parameter) and performs a choice. The problems arise because the choice is stated by returning a pointer to the chosen element (an iterator, in fact), but I can't find a way to return a C++ pointer as a result of a python function. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly doable, but you don't really have enough details.  What you really need to do is create a c++ function that calls your python function, proceses the python result and returns a c++ result.  To paraphrase (let's assume I have a boost `object` called func that points to some python function that parses a string and returns an int):

```
using boost::python;
A* test(const std::string &foo) {
    object module = import("mymodule");
    object func = module.attr("myfunc");
    // alternatively, you could set the function by passing it as an argument
    // to a c++ function that you have wrapped

    object result = func(foo);
    int val = extract<int>(result);
    return new A(val); // Assumes that you've wrapped A.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// file: https://github.com/layzerar/box2d-py/blob/master/python/world.cpp
struct b2ContactFilter_W: b2ContactFilter, wrapper<b2ContactFilter>
{
    bool ShouldCollide(b2Fixture* fixtureA, b2Fixture* fixtureB)
    {
        override func = this->get_override("ShouldCollide");
        if (func)
        {
            return func(ref(fixtureA), ref(fixtureB)); //ref is boost::ref
        }
        return b2ContactFilter::ShouldCollide(fixtureA, fixtureB);
    }

    bool ShouldCollideDefault(b2Fixture* fixtureA, b2Fixture* fixtureB)
    {
        return b2ContactFilter::ShouldCollide(fixtureA, fixtureB);
    }
};

class_<b2ContactFilter_W, boost::noncopyable>("b2ContactFilter")
        .def("ShouldCollide", &b2ContactFilter::ShouldCollide, &b2ContactFilter_W::ShouldCollideDefault)
    ;
```

Is this what you need ?